# validation in javascript..so not getting message box

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

in my program I have kept validation using required in textbox and submit in button. my problem is when empty values given validation occurs. but message `Record Saved` is not displayed. when I remove submit & keep button, I get  message `Record Saved` but   validation don't occurs...

my JavaScript is......

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Save").click(function () {
            if (($("#txtName").val()) != "" )
            {
                var ds = $("#CollecionID").data("igCombo").value();
                $.ajax({ url: '/Home/SaveCollectionmaster?Name=' + ($("#txtName").val())
                             + '&Description=' + ($("#txtDescription").val())
                             + '&ds=' + ds,
                    success: function (message) {
                        alert(message);
                        $("#txtName").get(0).value = "";
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<form id="ss">
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
        <input type="text" id="txtName"  required="txtName"class="textarea" />
        <input type="submit"  id="Save" value="Save"  class="button" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

my c# code is....

```
[ActionName("SaveCollectionmaster")]
public ContentResult SaveCollectionmaster(string Name, string Description, string ds)
{
    DB.TblType detail = new DB.TblType();
    detail.Type = Name;
    detail.description =Description;
    DB_Linq.TblTypes.InsertOnSubmit(detail);
    DB_Linq.SubmitChanges();
    return Content("Record Saved");
}
```

Both validation message & message box have to come

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using a `submit` button. This will post the form to the server once your javascript function is complete. You have two options, have your javascript function return `false` this will prevent the form from posting or change the input type to `button`.